# How to use amazon S3 in c#?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I want to download files with amazon s3. I have bucketname, secret and access key.

What is region endpoint and how do I set it can I download files with this information I have

```
string accessKey="access key";
string secretKey="secret key";
string bucketName="my bucket name";
string directoryFile="File directory";



TransferUtility utility=new TransferUtility(client);

 //download.   --But this line error.

Error is:The request we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
Check your key and signing method.
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [official sample](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html). Check the credentials and the key name, as invalid values for those may result in the error that you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Check your directory and file name. directory is different on desktop and server.

```
string accessKey="my access key";
string secretKey="my secret key";
string bucketName="my bucket name";
string directoryFile=@"C:\MyDownloadFile"; //Please check your directory access

TransferUtility fileTransferUtility =
    new TransferUtility(
        new AmazonS3Client("ACCESS-KEY-ID", "SECRET-ACCESS-KEY", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.CACentral1));

// Note the 'fileName' is the 'key' of the object in S3 (which is usually just the file name)
fileTransferUtility.Download(filePath, "my-bucket-name", fileName); // check file name as your keyName
```

Answer (score 0):

The error infers its a Credential problem or perhaps you don't specify the KeyName - usually the keyname is just the files name:

```
string keyName="file.txt";
string bucketName="mybucket";
string directoryFile="C:\\MyDownloadFile";

TransferUtility utility=new TransferUtility(client);
fileTransferUtility.Download(directoryPath,bucketName,keyName);
```